# How to handle ForeignKey in Angular 2

Tags: angular

I am newbie to angular 2. I want to consume Consuming a REST API with foreign keys.
categories=
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "books": [
            1,
            2
        ]
},
{
        "id": 2,
        "books": [
            4,
            7
        ]
}
]

books=[

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "category": 1,
    "title": "Book1",
 },
{
    "id": 2,
    "category": 1,
    "title": "Book2",
},
{
    "id": 4,
"category": 2,
   "title": "Book4",

},
```

{
        "id": 7,
        "category": 2,
       "title": "Book4",

```
}
```

]

How can I do something like category.id==book.category ?